# How best to shift weight of small load bearing wall section

Tags: framing, load-bearing

I know, everyone's favorite topic from homeowners, load-bearing walls.

Long story short, I've attached sketches of current situation and preferred situation. My wife really wants it gone (and replaced with engineered beam) but the $4800 contractor quote makes that not an option.

Plan A (https://imgur.com/2jTmqfe): Remove king/jack studs from existing section of wall, replacing with 3-4 studs going straight to an added header the same dimension as the existing header to the left and right (preferred method that allows more space to navigate around the post)

Plan B (https://imgur.com/nDWMid0): Leave it alone and just wrap in drywall (not preferred because of tight space constraints this creates)

The width of this wall section is 23", would like to be able to reduce to just the width of a few 2x4s (4.5"-6")

Just wanna know, can I do what I've sketched in Plan A, adding the double 2x10 with a few studs (sitting on a PT bottom plate on concrete)

Comment: What's the existing condition?  All I see is Plan A and Plan B, which I presume are proposed conditions.

Comment: It is currently as shown in Plan B. Plan B is essentially just installing drywall over the current stud layout. It's the 2-2x10 header with double 2x4 top plate, single 2x4 plate below the header, and the 2 jack and 2 king studs going to the floor (sitting on pressure-treated bottom plate) and sitting on the concrete slab foundation floor

Comment: So existing conditions is a double 2x10 single span?

Comment: As is there are double 2x10 headers on the left and right  of this section we're dealing with. Currently no header between the two pairs of jack/king studs seen in "Plan B" 
 https://imgur.com/usye3gF

Comment: So your plan is to fit double 2x10 pieces between the existing 2x10s? I'm not sanguine about simple toe nails supporting those butt ends.